# Get the value of a selected ComboBoxItem WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, combobox

How can i get the value of a selected comboBox Item on WP7?I tried this code:
`string val = MonthBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            textBlock1.Text = val;`
but it didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I had to choose "SelectionBoxItem" instead of "SelectedItem" , i finally found it !Thanks everybody for the help ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `ComboBox` on Windows Phone. Instead use the [ListPicker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/WP7ListPicker.aspx) from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com).

Comment: And how can i get the value of selected ListPicker Item? @Claus Jørgensen

Comment: I tried 'ListPicker.SelectedItemProperty.ToString();' but it didn't work!

Comment: @Martech you want `SelectedItem` not it's backing property.

Comment: I'm still stack. I didn't find the right code to get my ListPicker SelectedItem Value in the TextBox x(

Comment: @MarTech this is why you need go practice some basic C#. If you don't understand how objects works in C#, then you'll not be able to understand any answer we can provide. So spend some time reading up on the basics, and you'll understand eventually.